# How to add same class into many elements at a time?

Tags: jquery, html, css

On my website, I have describe my product using an unordered list. And there are too many products. Now I want to add a little animation on the product button that is in the second last position. I have create a class in my css file that is contain my animation, and I want to add this animation on that second last `li`.

I know I can manually add a different class to that `li`, but the problem is there are 713 unordered list or product description.

So is this possible to add a class to all of those second last `li` at a time.

**My product description is look like.**

```
<ul class="product_details">
   <li>Text</li>
   <li>Text</li>
   <li>Text</li>
   <li>Text</li>
   <li>Text</li>
   <li>Text</li>
   <li>Text</li>
   <li>Text</li>
   <li>Text</li>
   <li>Text</li>
   <li>Text</li>
   <li>Text</li>
   <li>Text</li>
   <li>Text</li>
   <li>Text</li>
   <li class="HERE_I_WANT_TO_ADD_THAT_CLASS">Button</li>
   <li>Text</li>
</ul>
```

I have search on internet but did not get a solution.

Comment: Simply you can use 
$(".product_details > li:last").prev();

Comment: Or you can simply use a text-editor with mass search&replace ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible, you need to know the use of jQuery or CSS selectors.

*There are two ways to do it.*

**USING CSS**

```
. product_details li:nth-child(16) {
    /* YOUR ANIMATION GOES HERE */
}
```

**USING jQuery**

```
$('.product_details li:nth-child(16)').addClass('YOUR_ANIMATION_CLASS');
```

Comment: thanks for the css solution, I don't know jquery, so i am avoiding to use it

Comment: css solution presumes you know amount of the elements beforehand. I'd advise to use `:nth-last-child(2)` (see answer by Snehal Shan)

Answer (score 11):

Use the following:

```
$( "ul li:nth-last-child(2)" ).addClass( "CLASS_YOU_WANT_TO_ADD" );
```

The nth-last-child will return the last element and add 2 will give the second last element from the list.

Answer (score 3):

Try this : Find last `li` inside product_details and then do `prev()` to get second last `li` and add your class

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.product_details').find('li:last').prev('li').addClass('HERE_I_WANT_TO_ADD_THAT_CLASS');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here i want to add one more solution

if you want add only css3 animation, this will help you. also don't want add any classes

```
.product_details li:nth-last-child(-1){

}
```

Comment: Are you sure there even exists such a construct? (`:last-child(n)`)